# Can we Create folders under Container at run time in Azure blob storage?

Tags: typescript, azure, azure-storage

I have below code in typescript. which is used to Upload local files to Azure blob storage in the given container.
Can we create a folder each time in that container, whenever upload is happening and files should be uploaded to that folder in the container.

Path:
Storage Account - Container  - Folder -- Files.

```
const STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME = "*******";
    const ACCOUNT_ACCESS_KEY = "************************";

    
  const containerName = "container1";
  const localFilePath = "../tree2.jpg";

  const credentials = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME, ACCOUNT_ACCESS_KEY);

  const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(`https://${STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME}.blob.core.windows.net`,credentials);

  const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
  
   const fileName = path.basename(localFilePath);
   const blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(fileName);
   const blockBlobClient = blobClient.getBlockBlobClient();
    blockBlobClient.uploadFile(localFilePath);
```

Comment: Blob storage doesn't have "folders" in the conventional sense. They have "virtual folders" mainly used for a UI to display a hierarchy. Blob storage has paths separated by the '/' character. Saying that, you can't use "." or ".." to describe your path. You have to use absolute paths. For example: "this/is/my/path/file.txt" is the actual name of the file. It may look like a directory structure, but it's actually the name of the file.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try to use this code :

```
const blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient("foldername/fileName");
```